# Prevenir el uso de túneles ssh

Tags: javascript, linux, networking, security

Cuando me quiero conectar a un equipo que está detrás de un firewall muy restrictivo, o el equipo no tiene una IP pública, cuando no uso la gran y dudosa herramienta *gsocket*, por lo general hago un proxy jump:

1. Creo un equipo bastión con IP pública (uso *gcloud* porque soy huevón)
2. Creo un script de forma `ssh <bastion> -R <puerto remoto>:127.0.0.1:22` y lo corro en la máquina remota
3. Me conectó a la máquina objetivo a través del bastión usando la característica de ProxyJump de ssh

Lo cual me llevó a preguntarme, ¿Existe una manera de prevenir que un usuario haga esto?

Es decir, ¿Existe alguna manera de evitar que un usuario, detrás de una LAN y un firewall, se conecte a un bastión usando ssh?

O, lo que es casi equivalente a decir, ¿Es posible prohibir el uso de ssh o sus conexiones a un usuario o a un equipo?

Lo primero que se me ocurrió fue usar *iptables* para dropear las conexiones salientes desde el puerto 22. Pero un usuario puede configurar ssh para correr desde otro puerto.

Luego un amigo me comentó de la opción *AllowTcpForwarding* pasarla a *no*.

Lo otro que se me ocurrió fue impedirle al usuario instalar *ssh* al meter algún proceso que lo busque y lo desinstale periódicamente. Pero un usuario puede compilar su propio ssh y llamarlo y usarlo y ponerlo donde quiera.

Al final, preguntando, se me ocurrió restringir la salida de datos de todos los puertos usando *iptables*, y dejándole al usuario que la salida sea a demandada personalmente al sysadmin :/

Esto es pensando que el usuario no es un sudoer de su equipo, porque podría usar *iptables* para cambiar las reglas de nuevo, o editar el *sshd_config*.

Ahora, ¿Pero qué sucede si el usuario es un sudoer de su equipo?

¿Se puede, a través de algún artilugio a nivel router o de la red, o del SO, digamos, empresarial o académica, evitar este tipo de conexiones?

De lo contrario, la seguridad basada en "estar detrás de un firewall", o sólo permitida a través de un bastión, sería tan sólo seguridad basada en que los usuarios no sepan sobre un remote port forwarding.

### Update 1

Me acaban de comentar sobre un concepto controversial llamado "Deep packet inspection".

Comment: Interesante cuestión, el problema no es específico de SSH como te habrás dado cuenta, y es también el principio de las _reverse shells_, supongo que la única forma de evitarlo sería, mediante un firewall interno o externo a la máquina, bloquear las conexiones salientes, restringiéndolas tanto como sea necesario.

Comment: La cosa es que, si el usuario es el sudoer del equipo detrás de una LAN, cualquier intento de poner un bastión para poder acceder, o bloquear ciertas conexiones desde la LAN podrían ser considerados como "seguridad basada en la oscuridad". Es decir, seguridad basada en que no te sepas estos hacks.

Comment: La idea no es en especial que no se sepa, de hecho en la organización tendrían que definirse políticas de acceso conocidas por todos. Respecto al edit, insisto en que el problema no es SSH en particular, puesto que un actor malicioso puede usar protocolos arbitrarios para establecer una shell inversa. Véase dnscat2 (https://github.com/iagox86/dnscat2), que solo a través de mensajes DNS establece todo un sistema command-and-control.

Comment: "Políticas de acceso conocidas por todos". Creo que si pusieras eso como respuesta, te la pondría como válida. Muchas gracias por tus comentarios. Revisaré el README al respecto.

Comment: Por cierto, un amigo me comentó sobre deep packet inspection para esta pregunta, que no se me hace un concepto descabellado, pero las herramientas al respecto son un telón negro para mi.

Comment: Mientras que un usuario pueda ejecutar programas arbitrarios en su máquina, me temo que no es posible. Por ejemplo, se puede crear un programa que realice peticiones HTTPS y el *payload* sean imágenes con datos ocultos (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography). Y ya tendrías una comunicación bidireccional, encriptada, y oculta en simples imágenes.

Comment: Ei. Es la conclusión a la que he estado llegando: 1) Deep packet inspection ( :/ ), 2) Políticas claras sobre el acceso, 3) Truquearle el SO, osea, no darle el control completo de la máquina de trabajo

Comment: Los firewall restrictivos suelen tener inspección de paquetes; WAF e IPF tienen muchas opciones para filtrar peticiones "sospechosas". Hay otra filosofíá relevante acá y es ZeroTrust. Das acceso a recursos teniendo en cuenta el contexto, no sólo las credenciales. Así, el bastión debería tener instalados recursos y autenticarse ante el gestor de la solución ZeroTrust para poder acceder al recurso y al puerto específico, por ejemplo. Disclaimer: trabajo en una empresa que ofrece una solución de este tipo

Comment: No se si me falta una parte, pero en lineas generales, si se puede hacer ssh, se puede hacer tuneling, si no confias en un usuario no le das ssh, si el usuario es sudoer y no confias... no hay mas que poner una restricción en una capa mas baja, por ejempo quitar el acceso público a la red. En los casos similares que conozco, la red es inaccesible, sino a travez de una vpn, a través de la cual también se puede hacer tuneling, pero se supone que ya ahí hay 2 instancias de control.